# Custom encoding function error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have created a function that takes two string inputs from the user and returns one string value. It is intended to take one string holding a message or some form of text, and another holding a custom alphabet entered by the user. It will then return the message inputted by the user encoded using the alphabet provided by the user.

example:

```
text_to_encode = "abcd"
user_alphabet = "bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

print(encode(text_to_encode, user_alphabet))
```

The encoding of my function works fine, however when it comes to a string containing spaces, it ignores the spaces and prints the encoded message without any spaces.

example:

```
text_to_encode = "ab cd"
user_alphabet = "bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

print(encode(text_to_encode, user_alphabet))
```

The output of this would be:  "BCDE" when it SHOULD be "BC DE".

I don't know where I'm going wrong with my code, any help would be appreciated. This is what I have:

```
def encode(text_to_encode, user_alphabet):
 text_to_encode_list = []
 for ch in text_to_encode:
  text_to_encode_list.append(ch)

 user_alphabet_list = []
 for ch in user_alphabet:
  user_alphabet_list.append(ch)

 original_alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
 original_alphabet_list = []
 for ch in original_alphabet:
  original_alphabet_list.append(ch)

 result = []
 for value_x in text_to_encode_list:
  flag = False
  for value_y in original_alphabet:
   if value_x == original_alphabet_list[value_y]:
    flag = True
    result.append(user_alphabet_list[value_y])
    break
 if flag == False:
  result.append(value_x)

 encoded_text = ""
 for value in result:
  encoded_text += value

 return encoded_text.upper()
```

Comment: Why are you converting all the strings to lists? You can access strings by index the same as lists.

Comment: I am fairly new to programming... thanks for the tip!

Comment: And instead of nested loops, you should create a dictionary that contains the mapping from original alphabet to user alphabet.

Comment: I was aware of that method, however I was attempting to create my own function from scratch.

Comment: You should at least use something like `find()` to get the position of an element, rather than your own loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
 if flag == False:
  result.append(value_x)
```

Needs to be in the `for value_x` loop. You have it after the end of the loop, so it only works if the last character in the input isn't found.